# Enviar e Receber pacotes (packets) em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Bom, vou tentar explicar a situação:

Estou estudando NodeJS e para isso resolvi reescrever o código do lado servidor de uma aplicação que originalmente foi escrito em C/C++, e esse servidor recebe pacotes (packets) em hexadecimal da aplicação client, a questão é: como receber esses pacotes (packets) em NodeJS ?

Cheguei a criar um socket para a conexão mas dei uma travada, segue o código feito:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8281;
var io = require('socket.io')(port);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
     var address = socket.handshake;
    console.log('Nova conexão de: ' + JSON.stringify(address, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código completo para podermos testar também? Sem ver o resto da aplicação e a parte do cliente não sabemos o que pode ser o problema. Qual foi o problema que tiveste? algum erro ou somente "não acontece nada"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe básica do node.js utilizada para comunicação em TCP chama-se "net".

Abaixo um exemplo de servidor e cliente feitos com a classe "net". O original (com comentários) está em http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

---

### server

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

net.createServer(function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');
    });
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

---

### client

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

---

Comment: Muito obrigado José X, era exatamente o que eu precisava para dar andamento melhor no que estou fazendo, resposta perfeita!